# how to restore MySQL database from ibdata, ibdata logs

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, mysql

unfortunately I faced problem with server
then server was getting crashed 
only what i have are ibdata, ibdata logs  files and I totally lost frm files
my question is
how I can restore my database without frm files?
please help